# Nested condition in numpy and pandas are not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to generate a data frame with two columns, 'date' and 'amount'. The date goes from 2018-01 to 2020-12, however, the column 'amount' has to be filled **based on the following rule:**

(1). If date is between '2018/01' and '2019/01', then take starting value of 1000 and for any following rows multiply the previous value by 1.06.

(2). If date is between '2019/02' and '2020/01', then take last value of (1.) as the starting value and for any following rows multiply the previous value by 1.04.

(3). If date is between >2020/01, then take last value of (2.) as the starting value and for any following rows multiply the previous value by 1.02.

My code looks like this:

```
df['amount'] =  
np.where((df['date']>='2018/01') & (df['date']<='2019/01'), 
1000 * (1+g_2018) ** df.index,  

np.where( (df['date']>='2019/02') & (df['date']<='2020/01'),
int(df.loc[df['date'] == '2019/01', 'amount'].iloc[0]) * (1+g_2019) ** (df.index-12),

np.where( (df['date']>='2020/02'),
int(df.loc[df['date'] == '2020/01', 'amount'].iloc[0]) * (1+g_2020) ** (df.index-24),

False      
 )))
```

The output does apply only the first rule (1.) but ignores the rest. Thus, it only fills row 0-12 and then all subsequent values are 0...why?

```
    date    amount
0   2018/01 1000.000000
1   2018/02 1060.000000
2   2018/03 1123.600000
3   2018/04 1191.016000
4   2018/05 1262.476960
5   2018/06 1338.225578
6   2018/07 1418.519112
7   2018/08 1503.630259
8   2018/09 1593.848075
9   2018/10 1689.478959
10  2018/11 1790.847697
11  2018/12 1898.298558
12  2019/01 2012.196472
13  2019/02 0.000000
14  2019/03 0.000000...
```

Comment: I ran your code and did not see the described error.